# Php Spreadsheet reader - Not Reading First Page

Tags: php, spreadsheet

I am trying to read from an excel sheet using php spreadsheet reader.

```
require('excel/php-excel-reader/excel_reader2.php');
require('excel/SpreadsheetReader.php');

$uploadFilePath = 'batch_upload.xlsx';
$Reader = new SpreadsheetReader($uploadFilePath);
$Sheets = $Reader->Sheets();

foreach ($Sheets as $Index => $Name)
{
  echo 'Sheet #'.$Index.': '.$Name;

  $Reader -> ChangeSheet($Index);

  foreach ($Reader as $Row)
  {
    print_r($Row);
  }
}
```

If the spreadsheet contains only single page it is returning an empty array. But if there is a second sheet then for both sheet the returning value will be that of the second sheet. The first-sheet values are not processing.

xlsx sheets that i have used

https://ufile.io/c9qpn

https://ufile.io/d557h

The plugin git repo is https://github.com/nuovo/spreadsheet-reader

Thanks in advance.

Comment: we have no idea what excel_reader2.php or spreadsheetreader.php do

Comment: Those files are from plugin library. Attached the repo link.